# bassistance form validation input error event

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

In bassistance form validation plugin; I found **success** option in validate options parameter which is triggered whenever a valid input value is entered, not only on submissions

For example:

```
    success: function(label) {
        label.text("ok!"); //.addClass("success");
        label.addClass("success"); }
```

Is there any equivalent event that is triggered whenever An invalid value is entered ? not only on submissions ?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `errorPlacement` option.

It takes a jQuery object containing the error label as its first argument, just like `success`, and takes another jQuery object containing the invalid element as its second argument:

```
errorPlacement: function(label, element) {
    label.text("not OK").insertAfter(element);
}
```

Comment: errorPlacement happens just once, not for every invalid input

Comment: @AkramHassan, strange, since the function specified is responsible for appending the error labels to the document, it should be called once for each invalid element. Do you mean it is only called for the first one?

Comment: yes, just for the first time, i think it makes sense because it is just for placing the error element!

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem but found the solution after a bit of head-scratching. I realise you posted this a while back, but if anybody stumbles across this then it might prove useful.

You need to use the `highlight` configuration option, which is of type function.

```
// Triggers on all errors, regardless of event type
highlight: function (element) {
    $(element).parent().addClass('has-error');
}
```

Coupled with the success option, you now have control over both success events and all error events, even if these errors were triggered by onkeyup, onsubmit, onfocusout or onclick events.

```
// Triggers on success
success: function ($element) {
    $element.parent().removeClass('has-error');
}
```

Hope this helps somebody.